# How to kill spring boot application immediately after 1st unhandled exception globally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kill

I'd like to print unhandled exception into logs and then kill my spring boot application immediately. Is there a way to do it?

```
spring boot application runs;  
if unhandled exception happens somewhere in the code then:  
  print exception and stack trace into log;  
  kill application;    
end if.
```

Comment: This question is vague. This comment is also vague.

Comment: Tried to explain a bit ;<

Comment: You are trying to rip off the concept of exception handling itself.

Comment: No, I'm trying to get rid of exceptions thrown out of very deep in provided packages, I want it thrown right on spot when my code is wrong.